# Hive impersonation not working with custom authenticator provider

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've developed a custom authenticator provider and everything seems OK with regards to authentication: HiveServer2 starts well and authenticated connections are properly validated. Even, simple Hive queries work, such as `show tables`.

**The problem is when I try to execute a query from a remote Hive client. Since I've connected passing my credentials (user + password... well, not really a password, it is a token, but that's not relevant), and Hive configuration is ready for impersonation (see below), I expected HiveServer2 performed the query as my user. Nevertheless, it uses the `hive` user, which has no permissions on my HDFS user space.**

For instance, if I create a table:

```
> create external table mytable (name string, job string, age string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location '/user/frb/testdir'
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=hive, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/frb":frb:frb:drwxr-----
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:785)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
)
```

Regarding relevant configuration parameters, this is my configuration (simplified, not XML like):

`hive-site.xml`:

```
com.telefonica.iot.idm.endpoint=https://account.lab.fiware.org
hive.server2.enable.doAs=true
hive.server2.authentication=CUSTOM
hive.server2.custom.authentication.class=com.telefonica.iot.cosmos.hive.authprovider.OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl
```

`core-site.xml`:

```
hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups=*
hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts=*
```

You can have a look on the custom Hive authenticator provider code [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/cosmos-hive-auth-provider/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cosmos/hive/authprovider/OAuth2AuthenticationProviderImpl.java).

I'm using Hive 0.13.0

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Where are these `hadoop.proxyuser..` properties set?

Comment: `hadoop.proxyuser...` settings are within `core-site.xml`. The other ones are within `hive-site.xml`. I've checked they are accessible from the custom auth provider.

Comment: @frb Did you restart hiveserver2 after making the changes?

Comment: Yes, several times :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "hive.metastore.execute.setugi" is set to true as in step 1 and step 2 in HiverServer2 host node(s) and Hive Metastore host node(s) respectively. Note that this property must be set on both the client/gateway nodes, HiverServer2 and Hive Metastore host nodes.

Reference: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+User+Impersonation

Comment: `hive.metastore.execute.setugi` is set to `true` in `hive-site.xml`. This properties files is located at the node running Hive Client, HiveServer2, Hive Metastore and MySQL server, thus it is accessible to all those services.

Answer (score 0):

If your Hive is Kerberos protected, you my need to make some modification to the way you authenticate. Kerberos doesn't allow impersonation via token

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_hdfs_proxy_users.html#hdfs_proxy_users__section_fvj_fmp_dw